# onClick from button to function

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

This is a work in progress (a calculator and some other stuff), but what I'm trying to do at the moment is whenever you type in some number into the results of the calculator, and you press "+" the onclick will call checkValidity which will determine if what you typed in was integer or not integer. It will send an alert saying integer or not an integer. My issue is that the onclick won't do anything. I tried emptying the checkValidity function of everything but alert("test); and it still won't work. Could someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script type="text/javascript>">
         function checkValidity()
         {
            var Calculator = document.getElementById("Calculator")
         if (Calculator.Result.value === parseInt(test, 10))
            {
            alert("Integer!");
            }
            else
            {
            alert("Not an integer, press C");
            }
         }
      </script>
      <form name="Calculator">
         First name:
            <br>
               <input type="text" name="firstname">
            <br>
         Last name:
            <br>
               <input type="text" name="lastname">
            <br>
         Student ID:
            <br>
               <input type="text" name="ID">
            <br>
         Biography:
            <br>
               <textarea maxlength=30 rows="2" cols="30">
               </textarea>
            <br>
         Result:
         <table border="1" style="width:100%">
            <input type="text" name="Result" size="12">
            <tr>
               <td><Input type="button" Name="zero" Value="0" OnClick="Calculator.Result.value += '0'"> </td>
               <td><Input type="button" Name="one" Value="1" OnClick="Calculator.Result.value += '1'"></td>
               <td><Input type="button" Name="two" Value="2" OnClick="Calculator.Result.value += '2'"></td>
               <td><Input type="button" Name="three" Value="3" OnClick="Calculator.Result.value += '3'"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td><Input type="button" Name="four" Value="4" OnClick="Calculator.Result.value += '4'"></td>
               <td><Input type="button" Name="five" Value="5" OnClick="Calculator.Result.value += '5'"></td>
               <td><Input type="button" Name="six" Value="6" OnClick="Calculator.Result.value += '6'"></td>
               <td><Input type="button" Name="seven" Value="7" OnClick="Calculator.Result.value += '7'"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td><Input type="button" Name="eight" Value="8" OnClick="Calculator.Result.value += '8'"></td>
               <td><Input type="button" Name="nine" Value="9" OnClick="Calculator.Result.value += '9'"></td>
               <td><Input type="button" Name="plus" Value="+" OnClick="checkValidity()"></td>
               <td><Input type="button" Name="minus" Value="-" OnClick="Calculator.Result.value += '-'"></td>
            </tr>      
            <tr>
               <td><Input type="button" Name="equals" Value="=" OnClick="Calculator.Result.value = eval(Calculator.Result.value)"></td>
               <td><Input type="button" Name="divide" Value="/" OnClick="Calculator.Result.value += '/'"></td>
               <td><Input type="button" Name="multiply" Value="*" OnClick="Calculator.Result.value += '*'"></td>
               <td><Input type="button" Name="clear" Value="C" OnClick="Calculator.Result.value = ''"></td>
            </tr>
         </table>
         <span id="HoursWorkedThisWeek"></span>
         <Input type="button" Name="Save" Value="Save" OnClick="Calculator.HoursWorkedThisWeek = Calculator.Result.value">
         <Input type="button" Name="Submit" Value="Submit">
      </form>
   </head>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to do some reading on onClick (not OnClick). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick

Comment: Looks like there's no element with id of `Calculator`.  There's a form with a `name="Calculator"`, but then there's no `Result` property on a form, either...  There's more than just an onclick problem here...

Comment: @taylorc93, it's onclick

Comment: @NK, you're totally right.  Stupid typos :P

Comment: So first thigns first, onclick is case sensitive?

Comment: You have all your elements inside the `<head>`... Only the `<script>` should be inside the head, all the HTML elements should be inside a `<body>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this it worked

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>


   </head>
   <body>
    <form id="Calculator" name="Calculator">
         First name:
            <br>
               <input type="text" name="firstname">
            <br>
         Last name:
            <br>
               <input type="text" name="lastname">
            <br>
         Student ID:
            <br>
               <input type="text" name="ID">
            <br>
         Biography:
            <br>
               <textarea maxlength=30 rows="2" cols="30">
               </textarea>
            <br>
         Result:
         <table border="1" style="width:100%">
            <input type="text" name="Result" size="12">
            <tr>
               <td><Input type="button" Name="zero" Value="0" OnClick="Calculator.Result.value += '0'"> </td>
               <td><Input type="button" Name="one" Value="1" OnClick="Calculator.Result.value += '1'"></td>
               <td><Input type="button" Name="two" Value="2" OnClick="Calculator.Result.value += '2'"></td>
               <td><Input type="button" Name="three" Value="3" OnClick="Calculator.Result.value += '3'"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td><Input type="button" Name="four" Value="4" OnClick="Calculator.Result.value += '4'"></td>
               <td><Input type="button" Name="five" Value="5" OnClick="Calculator.Result.value += '5'"></td>
               <td><Input type="button" Name="six" Value="6" OnClick="Calculator.Result.value += '6'"></td>
               <td><Input type="button" Name="seven" Value="7" OnClick="Calculator.Result.value += '7'"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td><Input type="button" Name="eight" Value="8" OnClick="Calculator.Result.value += '8'"></td>
               <td><Input type="button" Name="nine" Value="9" OnClick="Calculator.Result.value += '9'"></td>
               <td><Input type="button" Name="plus" Value="+" OnClick="checkValid()"></td>
               <td><Input type="button" Name="minus" Value="-" OnClick="Calculator.Result.value += '-'"></td>
            </tr>      
            <tr>
               <td><Input type="button" Name="equals" Value="=" OnClick="Calculator.Result.value = eval(Calculator.Result.value)"></td>
               <td><Input type="button" Name="divide" Value="/" OnClick="Calculator.Result.value += '/'"></td>
               <td><Input type="button" Name="multiply" Value="*" OnClick="Calculator.Result.value += '*'"></td>
               <td><Input type="button" Name="clear" Value="C" OnClick="Calculator.Result.value = ''"></td>
            </tr>
         </table>
         <span id="HoursWorkedThisWeek"></span>
         <Input type="button" Name="Save" Value="Save" OnClick="Calculator.HoursWorkedThisWeek = Calculator.Result.value">
         <Input type="button" Name="Submit" Value="Submit">
      </form>
        <script type="text/JavaScript">
         function checkValid()
         {           
            var Calculator = document.getElementById("Calculator")
            var test =Calculator[4].value;
         if (parseInt(Calculator[4].value) === parseInt(test, 10))
            {
            alert("Integer!");
            }
            else
            {
            alert("Not an integer, press C");
            }
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You made a few small mistakes that caused your code to not work.
I'll explain them after this **working example**:

```js
function validate() {
    if (Calculator.Result.value == parseInt(Calculator.Result.value,10)) {
        alert("Integer!");
    } else {
        alert("Not an integer, press C");
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <form name="Calculator">
        First name: <br /><input type="text" name="firstname" /><br />
        Last name: <br /><input type="text" name="lastname" /><br />
        Student ID: <br /><input type="text" name="ID" /><br />
        Biography: <br /><textarea maxlength=30 rows="2" cols="30"></textarea><br />
        Result:
        <table border="1" style="width:100%;">
            <input type="text" name="Result" size="12" />
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" name="zero" value="0" onclick="Calculator.Result.value += '0'" /> </td>
                <td><input type="button" name="one" value="1" onclick="Calculator.Result.value += '1'" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="two" value="2" onclick="Calculator.Result.value += '2'" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="three" value="3" onclick="Calculator.Result.value += '3'" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" name="four" value="4" onclick="Calculator.Result.value += '4'" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="five" value="5" onclick="Calculator.Result.value += '5'" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="six" value="6" onclick="Calculator.Result.value += '6'" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="seven" value="7" onclick="Calculator.Result.value += '7'" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" name="eight" value="8" onclick="Calculator.Result.value += '8'" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="nine" value="9" onclick="Calculator.Result.value += '9'" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="plus" value="+" onclick="validate()" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="minus" value="-" onclick="Calculator.Result.value += '-'" /></td>
            </tr>      
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" name="equals" value="=" onclick="Calculator.Result.value = eval(Calculator.Result.value)" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="divide" value="/" onclick="Calculator.Result.value += '/'" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="multiply" value="*" onclick="Calculator.Result.value += '*'" /></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="clear" value="C" onclick="Calculator.Result.value = ''" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        
        <span id="HoursWorkedThisWeek"></span>
        <input type="button" name="Save" value="Save" onclick="Calculator.HoursWorkedThisWeek = Calculator.Result.value" />
        <input type="button" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
```

(**fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z8umk2c6/6/**)

- You had all your elements inside the `<head>` tag. Only the `<script>` should be inside the head (or better yet, in a separate JS-file), all the HTML elements should be inside a `<body>` tag.
- Your form didn't have an `id`, only a `name`. Therefor the variable `Calculator` (bad practice to use uppercase for variable-names) referred to nothing. In your case you don't even need the variable, because you just access the form by name directly, so I removed that variable at the start of the function.
  *(I recommend using ID's instead of names however, but that might just be personal preference.)*
- The `===` in the if-clause didn't work, it was too strict. `==` will work however.
- "test" in the if-clause was nothing, it had no value. I rewrote the if-clause so that the value is checked against the integer-value of itself. If that integer-value is equals the original value, you know the original was an integer already.

*And a few other mistakes that may or may not break the code, but were bad practice non the less:*

- `OnClick` should be `onclick` (all lowercase). Same goes for `Name` and `Value`.
- Some `<input>` were written with an uppercase: `<Input>`.
- `<br>` and `<input>` need their own closing tags, like so: `<br />` and `<input />`